# Removing XML data through a DGV

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a DataGridView which displays a list of rail cars and has several buttons for manipulating the list (Add, Edit, Delete, Save). The contents of the DGV come from an XML file and are saved back to the same file when the Save button is clicked. All functions of this form work perfectly with the exception of the Delete button. When I delete a rail car from the list and click Save, it takes the "deleted" row and re-appends it to the XML file in a very weird way (picture below).

Here is the code for the form (I'm only including the Save & Delete buttons and XML handling for ease of reading):

```
 public partial class SimulatedTrainEditor : Form
{
    //fileName and XML variables for serialization/deserialization
    const string fileName = "SimulatedTrain1.xml";
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BindingList<SimulatedTrain>));

    //Create BindingList object to hold XML data
    public BindingList<SimulatedTrain> NewSimulatedTrain = new BindingList<SimulatedTrain>();     

    public bool WereChangesMade;

    public SimulatedTrainEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LoadXML();
        
        this.dataGridViewSimulatedTrainEditor.DataSource = NewSimulatedTrain;
        this.dataGridViewSimulatedTrainEditor.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.dataGridViewSimulatedTrainEditor.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.WereChangesMade = false;
        this.buttonSaveXML.Enabled = false;
    }

    public void LoadXML()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                NewSimulatedTrain = (BindingList<SimulatedTrain>)xml.Deserialize(fs);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
    
     private void buttonRemoveRailCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentRow = this.dataGridViewSimulatedTrainEditor.CurrentRow;

        if (currentRow != null)
        {
            this.NewSimulatedTrain.RemoveAt(currentRow.Index);
            this.WereChangesMade = true;
            this.buttonSaveXML.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void buttonSaveXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //are there any changes?
        if (WereChangesMade)
        {
            //save the file if changes
            using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                xml.Serialize(fs, this.NewSimulatedTrain);
            }

            //Disable the SaveXML button when it's clicked to look for new edits after each save
            this.buttonSaveXML.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are screenshots of before and after I delete a row (this is just the bottom portion of the XML):

Before:
[image]

After (the red bit should be the end of the XML file):
[image]

You can see it tries to add another closing ArrayOfSimulatedTrain tag to the end after it throws in the row data that should have been deleted. I am still getting use to working with XML files, but in the few instances I've done this type of work before, I've never run into this particular issue.

Comment: Post the code for `SimulatedTrain`, as it's most likely related to how you've defined that class for serialization.

Comment: It was my FileMode that was wrong, causing the XML to get editing in really weird ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `FileStream` in `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` mode does not wipe the content of file before writing.

Editing the XML changes the length of the content that will be written in the file. If the new XML is shorter, you will have some leftovers at the end of the file. From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx#Anchor_2) :

> If you overwrite a longer string (such as “This is a test of the OpenWrite method”) with a shorter string (such as “Second run”), the file will contain a mix of the strings (“Second runtest of the OpenWrite method”).

You need to change the `FileMode` of the stream to `FileMode.Create` to overwrite the whole file :

```
//save the file if changes
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    xml.Serialize(fs, this.NewSimulatedTrain);
}
```

Comment: Good catch! I wasn't aware that it would handle the file editing in quite that manner - but I changed the FileMode and it looks like it's working pretty good now!